# OnPressed effect on font color

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making simple custom Text button

```
SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){},
          splashColor: Colors.black12,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Done',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Now this works great however the effect on onTap event is around the text

[image]

How to make that effect to be on the text font only or if that is not possible change color of the text on tapped down and change it back on release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing the color of the text when pressed down, you can use the `onHighlightChanged` event handler of InkWell.

In your class declare a color property:

```
Color textColor = Colors.white;
```

And change your InkWell implementation:

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () {},
   splashColor: Colors.transparent,
   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
   onHighlightChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
         textColor = value ? Colors.white70 : Colors.white;
      });
   },
   child: Center(
      child: Text(
         Done',
         style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: textColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
         ),
      ),
   ),
)
```

**Note:**

1. You have to set the `splashColor` as transparent
2. You have to set the `highlightColor` as transparent

Comment: Great.. that works well. It is without animation but I don't really care about it.. Is there any chance to transfer it into state less widget though?

Comment: @delmin You are welcome. Happy Coding!!! For stateless widget, I'll try and if it works out will update the answer and notify you :)

Comment: @delmin: You have to put the inkwell part in a separate stateful widget and define the text color defined inside that. I couldn't find any other way so far to do this with stateless widget.

Comment: That is fine.. I didn't think it will be possible. Thank you :)

Comment: @delmin Sure checking

Comment: No... don't worry... I had mistake in my code... sorry.. Thank you again :)